# inlineShape = inlineShapes.AddPicture() ; referring to any word file, not to my created Interop.Word.Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms-interop

My task is to open a word file, on a button1 click, and add an image to that word file at cursor position on button2 click so on button_click events I write:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = null;  
WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application(); //make the word application
documents = WordApp.Documents;
document = documents.Add(); //open a document in my created application
button2.visible=true;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
button1.visible=false;
selection = WordApp.Selection;
inlineShapes = selection.InlineShapes;
inlineShape = inlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\MyPicture1.Jpeg"); // add picture to my created application document
}
```

every thing works file, But problem is, that if i manually open a new word application after button1 click (2 documents open), and image gets added to the 2nd document if the cursor is there.

I want that every time on button 2 click, the image should get added to 
`WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()` only, no mater on which document the cursor is. Please help....

I think I am making some mistake at creating the "selection" object , I think i am not properly refering it to wordApp. pls help :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you don't add your document to your application. so it doesn't matter for the application on what document you are working. replace  this`document = documents.Add(); //open a document in my created application`:

to

```
 this document = app.Documents.Add(new Document());
```

that should solve your problem